# Connect a java program to a remote oracle database

Tags: java, jdbc, oracle11g

I want to establish a connection between my java program and my oracle server that I installed on a virtual machine of my PC.I try the following code :

```
 connection=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@server:1521:dbname", "user", "password");
```

but here is the error:

```
java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Erreur d'E/S: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection.
```

I have nothing to install on my client machine other than my tools to develop java. My listener is started here its contents:

```
TST=
 (DESCRIPTION = 
  (ADDRESS+ (PROTOCOL = TCP) (HOST = oracleserver.domainesa)(PORT = 1521))
  (CONNECT_DATA =
   (SERVER = DEDICATED)
   (SERVICE_NAME = TST)
)
)
```

where oracleserver is the name of my server.
please help me.

Comment: Since you are using the thin JDBC driver, what you have in your TNS listener configuration is not relevant. The thin driver does not use your TNS listener configuration file.

Comment: Do you literally have `jdbc:oracle:thin:@server:1521:dbname` as the JDBC URL? Replace the `server` part of that string by the actual hostname or IP address of the database server.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;



public class DBConnection {

      //read this from a propery file is better
     public static final String DB_DRIVER = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
     public static final String DB_CONNECTION = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@ipaddress:port:sid";
     public static final String DB_USER = "username";
     public static final String DB_PASSWORD = "pwd";

        public static Connection getDBConnection() {

            Connection dbConnection = null;

            try {

                Class.forName(DB_DRIVER);

            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {

                System.out.println("Error driver JDBC: "+e.getMessage());

            }

            try {

            dbConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_CONNECTION,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD);
            return dbConnection;

            } catch (SQLException e) {

                System.out.println("Cannot open connection: "+e.getMessage());

            }

            return dbConnection;

        }

    }
```

Comment: i get the same error : The Network Adapter could not establish the connection

Comment: did you try to test the connection from a client ? it works ?